# Unexpected behavior from \vspace in a grid of \includegraphics

Tags: includegraphics, grids, vspace

I am trying to produce a grid of plots using the code below. Due to the sizing, the seventh plot is vertically offset a bit, as can be seen in the first image. But adding \vspace{-0.2in} to before the seventh \includegraphics unexpectedly shifts the *ninth* plot, instead of the seventh, as seen in the second image. What can I do to fix this?

```
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=0.318\textwidth]{fits_suss2p_SS4/fit_isodoublet-S1-P000-A1g_1-ROT-0_21000A1g_1-ROT-0T8-26_4.pdf}
  \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{fits_suss2p_SS4/fit_isodoublet-S1-P000-A1g_1-ROT-1_21000A1g_1-ROT-1T7-26_4.pdf}
  \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{fits_suss2p_SS4/fit_isodoublet-S1-P000-A1g_1-ROT-2_21000A1g_1-ROT-2T4-26_4.pdf}\\
  \includegraphics[width=0.318\textwidth]{fits_suss2p_SS4/fit_isodoublet-S1-P000-A1g_1-ROT-3_21000A1g_1-ROT-3T18-26_0.pdf}
  \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{fits_suss2p_SS4/fit_isodoublet-S1-P000-A1g_1-ROT-4_21000A1g_1-ROT-4T7-26_4.pdf}
  \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{fits_suss2p_SS4/fit_isodoublet-S1-P000-A1g_1-ROT-5_21000A1g_1-ROT-5T14-26_0.pdf}\\
  \includegraphics[width=0.318\textwidth]{fits_suss2p_SS4/fit_isodoublet-S1-P000-A1g_1-ROT-6_21000A1g_1-ROT-6T12-26_0.pdf}
  \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{fits_suss2p_SS4/fit_isodoublet-S1-P000-A1g_1-ROT-7_21000A1g_1-ROT-7T13-26_0.pdf}
  \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{fits_suss2p_SS4/fit_isodoublet-S1-P000-A1g_1-ROT-8_21000A1g_1-ROT-8T12-26_0.pdf}\\
  \includegraphics[width=0.318\textwidth]{fits_suss2p_SS4/fit_isodoublet-S1-P000-A1g_1-ROT-9_21000A1g_1-ROT-9T5-26_4.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

[image: bad grid]
[image]

Comment: better use \raisebox to raise the one picture. \vspace is inserted between lines.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is certainly enough of a solution to be posted as an answer.